# How to get an excerpt of a table in Excel in a different table?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have got an Excel document that is used as patient database for a practice. In the first table there is a complete list of all patients with the date of their first appointment and (if applicable) the date of their final appointment.

In the second table, I would like to have a list of all current patients (no final appointment). In the third table, I would like to have a list of all patients that are done (have a final appointment). Final appointments are only entered after the patient has shown up, so there is no need for a date check.

Is there a way to extract these sub-tables from the main table?

Comment: You can do this in Excel with some formulas, named ranges, and/or pivot tables, but this is really a job for a database.

Comment: I remember having that done in older versions of Excel with some kind of DB functions. However, couldn't find these functions in Excel 2007 anymore.

Comment: I know this is not a typical Excel job and myself, I would definitely use some other tool for it. My father would not. Ho-hum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about filter by first appointment or final appointment?...if you dont care with only one table...

Comment: that is kind of what I did in the end. It is not really elegant as you have to create a copy of the original table, but it works. My father is happy.